# mySQL adding 1 to a number for multiple updated rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Hey all i have the following update for my table in mySQL:

```
$dbBuilder = '';

foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    if ($value != 'APPROVE') {
        $dbBuilder = $value . ", " . $dbBuilder;
    }
}

$dbBuilder = '(' . rtrim($dbBuilder, ", ") . ')';

UPDATE userCase SET Accepted = 1 WHERE CaseNum in $dbBuilder
```

Works fine as it should... but now i needed to modify it to allow a new QNum for **each** of whatever CaseNum.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT QNum FROM userCase ORDER BY QNum DESC limit 1");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $QNum = $row["QNum"] + 1;
    break;
}

UPDATE userCase SET Accepted = 1, QNum = " . $QNum . " WHERE CaseNum in $dbBuilder
```

Doing it that way above would set **QNum** to the same number for **all CaseNum** in "in". It needs to be unique (as in, adding a 1 to the QNum for each new row).

It only needs to be 1 more than the last QNum in the table. So when someone "approves" a few things **(lets say 3 things)**, it goes to the query above and it needs to be **(lets say the last number is 4 in the DB)** so it needs to be **5,6,7**. The code i have now would just do **5,5,5**.

How would i accomplish this using the same **CaseNum in....** code above?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `QNum` a foreign key? Why does it need to be unique? Can you give us some more info about your data model?

Comment: `UPDATE yourTable SET theColumn = theColumn + 1` ?

Comment: It only needs to be 1 more than the last QNum in the table. So when someone "approves" a few things **(lets say 3 things)**, it goes to this query and it needs to be **(lets say the last number is 4)** so it needs to be **5,6,7**. The code i have now would just do **5,5,5**.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO i dont think that would work since its updating all the rows at once using the **in...** property.

Comment: Why not make `QNum` auto increment?

Comment: @DaveChen because all rows start with 0. They only start incrementing after they accept the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE userCase as u1 set Accepted = 1,
    QNum = (select 
        count(*) 
        from userCase as u2 
        where QNum is not null 
        or (
            u2.CaseNum in (...)
            and u2.CaseNum < u1.CaseNum
        ))
where CaseNum in (...)
```